# dart angular2 - null error when rendering an object in template

Tags: angular, dart

I'd like to write in my template something like :

```
 <span>{{myObject.myField}}</span>
```

However `myObject` is initialized in my `ngOnInit`, and my object seems to still be null when the page is rendered because I have the following error

```
NullError: method not found: 'myField' on null
```

If I only put in my template

```
 <span>{{myObject}}</span>
```

I can see the value of `myObject`.

Is there a way to initialize my object before `OnInit` ? Is there another way to display my data ?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the safe-navigation operator

```
<span>{{myObject?.myField}}</span>
```

to prevent errors while the model is not yet fully initialized

Alternatively you can wrap the elements with `*ngIf` to prevent them being rendered when the model is not yet initialized

```
<span *ngIf="myObject != null">{{myObject.myField}}</span>
```

This way you can cover bigger blocks or the whole template with a single `*ngIf` instead of adding `?` everywhere.

Comment: `<span>{{myObject?.myField}}</span>` works perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: In our project in same cases we usually add additional `*ngIf="myObject == null"` with some kind of spinner or `loading` lable as content, to indicate that component is not initialized yet. This approach can be easily converted to some custom guard control.

Comment: @StefanSvrkota Sure. Can you please delete yours. Dart is a nice language to build browser applications (and also server, and mobile, apps). Definitely worth a closer look ;-)